throwing an exception or returning Optional
In a service daemon coded in Java, we have services for getting various objects.
When we use these services forgetting an object, I wonder if

the method should return the object and throw an exception when It's not found
or return an Optional (this is what we opted for, so far)

Mind you , this service is not for a web service, so I have no use for a Global Exception Handler or such
class MyService
    public A getA(String key){
        ...
        // if A not found
        throw NotFoundException()
    }

vs

class MyService
    public Optional<A> getA(String key){
        ...
        // if A not found
        return Optional.empty()
    }


Required reading: Exceptions: The Right Way tl;dr: both approaches are right

At some point we have to clear out what an "opinion based" question means, cause this question can have perfectly valid answers for OP to pick from.

@Ccm: the reason I believe this is opinion-based is you can have two different answers which are equally valid, especially given the vague information in this question. If the OP can [edit] their question to include more information about the use case and the code, I would consider voting to reopen.

@GregBurghardt I am pretty sure the majority of questions here fall in that category.

Eh. I voted to reopen. The code might be generic, but this question is further constrained by it running as a service as opposed to a web API or server. And further constrained to "finding something".

I think the key question to figure out here is what is the impact not finding this something?  Is it a happy path scenario? Does it indicate that fundamental assumptions or constraints have been violated? In other words, what are you going to do or what can you do about it?

@PhilipKendall . I gotta say I find that article rather weak. There are quite some things in there I disagree with. I don't feel it should be thrown at beginners. -- Then, again, maybe, it's good enough for beginners and I'm just bitter and jaded by all the bad error handling code I've seen that refers back to such articles. :-)

For good order: in one case I definitely wanted to use Optional. However Java 8 backward compatibility was required. In the specific case using the unclean null was chosen as third alternative. There would be too many Exceptions (throws/catches) across the service border. (I detest null of course.) Clean code must be done be a convinced believer and not by a legalistic "believer."

There are two primary use cases for exceptions, which partially overlap:

You detect a problem that is unrelated to why this function might be called. It is unlikely that the calling code knows any better how to deal with this problem. Examples are out-of-memory conditions, or network errors where the calling code isn't aware that network communication is being used, etc. In these cases, exceptions can be used to perform a multi-level jump up the call-stack to a function that might be able to deal with the problem.

You detect a "this should not happen" problem, which is indicative of a bug in the system. Here, exceptions are used to halt the faulty calculations in their tracks. An example could be a retrieval function (getA), where it is known that the function can/should only be called with the id of an existing object.


For your example, both throwing an exception and returning an Optional are valid, but if it can somehow be expected that an ID gets passed in that doesn't correspond to an object, then the usual preference is to return an Optional.

IMHO, throwing an exception always exactly means "I could not fulfill my contract".
As an API developer, your steps should be:

Design the contract (with usefulness for your callers in mind).
Choose a method name that clearly indicates the contract.
Implement that method.

Designing the contract
Your contract is something around "find me an A for the given key", but that needs clarification, with the following two candidates:

"Get me an A with the given key." This version has no clause for not finding an A, so this contract can not be fulfilled then, meaning that an exception has to be thrown.
"Try to get me an A with the given key." This allows for not finding an A, so this outcome should be indicated in the return value, e.g. using an Optional<A>.

Contracts have to be designed with the typical callers in mind.
Analogy: Same as in business. You strive to offer products that meet your customers' needs. Knowing your customers helps, but it's not necessary to know every single customer's mindset in detail.
So, it helps to have some understanding of your callers, but it's not your responsibility to figure out the impact of not finding an A in each and every call stack that arrives at your API.
Back to your method's expected callers:

Do they expect the matching A to exist? Then the exception is preferrable, as it makes it easy for them to concentrate on the happy path.
Do you expect callers that will deal with the non-existence in their normal control flow? Then the Optional-based contract is better.
If you expect callers of both types, let them choose by offering both versions in different methods.

Naming the method
A name like getA() might imply (e.g. to me) that not returning an A is a violation of contract, but there are too many counter-examples out there to rely on that. Better be explicit in your naming, by using names like getAOrThrow() or TryGetA().
Implementing the method
Once the contract is clear, you can start coding. And if you chose to have both versions, you'd typically implement the exception-throwing one as a small wrapper around the Optional-based one.

The rule is that you throw exceptions in exceptional circumstances. For example, if the user enters a part number and you look up information about that part and return it, then it is normal that the user enters a wrong part code and nothing is found, no exception.
If every employee has a GUID and you can lookup further information about the employee by GUID then that GUID should always be correct. Throw an exception if the GUID doesn’t exist; there is very likely a bug to be fixed. On the other hand, if you don’t get the information because the internet connection is down, that is not an exception.

I've come to realize that the problem with the phrase "exceptions are for exceptional circumstances" is that it doesn't really help someone determine when to use them. It's pretty common to use exceptions for a network failure, but that's not an exceptional circumstance. I think a better way to think about it is analogous to an 'exception to the rule'. That is, for things that are awkward to handle in the normal control flow.

@JimmyJames, and it is even more nuanced than that. Exceptions stop the flow. And then when do you pull the pin on the hand grenade versus just returning early? In fact, I like to think of throwing an exception as "pulling the pin on a hand grenade." When should you just blow it up. Scuttle the ship. Walk away from this dumpster fire and wash your hands of it. That's when it's appropriate to throw an exception. And then, when to catch an exception? Well, when can you save the ship? What's the cost of letting your program crash? Such a complex thing masquerading as a simple throw.

@GregBurghardt Agreed, there's a lot to unpack.  I have to say though, if I had to worry about every single thing that could possibly go wrong (but probably won't) and what to do about it, I would never finish anything.

Trying to restrict exceptions for exceptional circumstances often doesn't work in practice.   Exceptions are really just a way of de-coupling the code which detects a problem away from the code which is able to handle that problem.    That could be a simple problem related to bad input, or an infrastructure problem.    A lot of modern libraries and frameworks in a lot of languages have realised this and taken advantage of it to help clean up their interfaces, so in many cases the use of exceptions is already decided elsewhere.

NaNs decided not to use exceptions “elsewhere”. Worked out fine. You certainly can reasonably avoid exceptions in most cases. Just remember you have to be able to reasonably explain what you did to new coders.

@BenCottrell arguably the most used programming language around, C, can live just fine without exceptions. Throwing exceptions out of everything is quite an annoying practice in Java (both the base libs and others), and abusing try-catch tends to turn your code in a convoluted mess. At least optional allow you to more easily follow control flow.
I personally don't see why this answer got so many downvotes, it is perfectly valid answer. I'm starting to think we have some serial downvoters here.

@candied_orange NaNs worked out fine? I think they are viral information destroyers. Like prions for software.

@Ccm "Throwing exceptions out of everything is quite an annoying practice in Java" I think this may conflate two things: 1. Checked exceptions are, I think, generally accepted as a failed experiment. 2. Some early libraries did indeed misuse exceptions. The first issue is annoying because you have to do something to propagate an exception, but it doesn't mean there are more exceptions being throw in Java libs, just that you are more aware of them. The second issue was just bad design. Throwing on a failed integer parse is just silly. This wasn't a common issue after early versions.

@JimmyJames I am still traumatized by exceptions being thrown when you close a file in java.

@Ccm Yeah or on closing an Oracle DB connection that was already closed. That's a fun day when that blows up your application in prod. There were some really stupid things that were more egregious, IMO. The whole way that XML parser implementations were loaded in an app through some sort of abstract factory bullcrap instead of just, you know, importing the library you wanted to use and using it. That was really horrible and completely unnecessary.

@JimmyJames oh no. You decided to divide by zero. Don’t blame the info destruction on the data type. Doing something forbidden by your algebra isn’t something an exception is going to save you from. Next time spin your black hole.

@candied_orange I can find innumerable blogs and discussions about how NaN issues can be avoided.  I can only find a few articles explaining why NaN is actually a good thing and they are all fairly academic in nature.  A fairly common complaint can be found in the data sciences space: running a model for hours, if not days, and ending up with nothing but NaN values as a result from even a just single NaN value creeping in. I fail to see the value in this or why we should think this is desirable. A major whole aspect of the design (signaling NaNs) isn't even used.

@JimmyJames that's not an info destruction complaint. That's  failing to fail fast.

@candied_orange I disagree.  The information destruction is a result of the contagious nature of NaN and not failing fast is a design 'feature' of NaN. The most common 'pro' of NaN I see is that it doesn't fail fast i.e., because it doesn't trap, it's faster. But try to explain that to someone who lost a day and potentially a lot of compute time (and money) that this was more efficient.

@candied_orange Is your argument that the NaN is well designed because it has a problematic feature that can be avoided through developer efforts?

@JimmyJames my argument is that NaN is a well designed number for a system of algebra that considers it an undefined number.

@candied_orange That's what I am disputing.

@JimmyJames ok so how would you design NaN?

@candied_orange I wouldn't.  I wouldn't add something that represents things that aren't numbers to a type meant to represent numbers.  We don't have NaI (not an integer) or NaC (not a character).  We do have null (which is roughly 'not an object') and that's considered a mistake and it isn't even contagious.

@JimmyJames so how do you justify zero? It breaks the algebra. So it’s not a number.

@JimmyJames “null” is not a mistake. Having values that are allowed to be null, with half of them logically capable to be null and the other half not, no way to specify, and being able to not test and instead crash, that is a mistake. NaNs make it possible to reduce the number of tests. Add four square roots and check whether the sum is NaN instead of checking each square root.

@candied_orange You don't see any alternative to creating a non-number number value?

@gnasher729 That you need to check at all is caused by non-numbers being stored in a number type.

@gnasher729 “null is not a mistake" that's your opinion. There are other opinions Nulls are unnecessary degenerate values.

@JimmyJames "Nulls are unnecessary" Oh if only it were true. If only I could force it to be true. If only I could count on it being true. Is there a parallel universe I could step into where no existing system will subject me to this gaping void in my polymorphism?

@candied_orange Rust doesn't have a Null value

@candied_orange I'm answering the question of what could be, not what is.  I am fully aware that nulls and NaN aren't going anywhere.  But that doesn't mean we should consider them optimal models for future designs.

@Ccm That's a strawman as you're essentially talking about a completely different language with a very different feature set and no support for exceptions.   Unless you're suggesting Java should be written in the same style as C;  however that is a lot more difficult than writing C-style code in C because it's a very different language which in many cases attempts to stop people from writing C-style code - for example, Java does not have C's #define macros).    Still, I think anybody who has ever tried simply writing C-style code in Java will have quickly discovered that it's a huge mistake.
